# Android Google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

I`m creating app with GPS map. Before I start understanding how to use the API in my app I have some questions.

1. Can I overlay an image on the map, without that the user knowing I use Google maps API?
2. Can I cut and use only specific area of the map and limit user to that map, lets say show only some amusement park and show the user location, and user cant go outside my map?

I need to show on an image the location of user, without navigation, should I use Google maps API or different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you want the Google Static Maps API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

This will generate an image of a map when you give it the latitude, longitude etc. You can then use this in an ImageView.

The advantage is that you don't have to create an expensive MapView, but it will not be interactive

Comment: Actually I need it to be interactive, I need that the user can see his location, zoom in and out. And most important the map needs to be offline.